# What does the following mean from בן יהוידע על עירובין כ״א: ? I understand the general gist but not the specifics

Tags: talmud-gemara

"**נָלִינָה בַכְּפָרִים", אַל תִּקְרִי: 'בַּכְּפָרִים', אֶלָּא 'בַּכּוֹפְרִים'.** הא דנקטה בעכו"ם 'נָלִינָה' ובישראל 'נַשְׁכִּימָה' (שיר השירים ז, יג)? נראה לי בס"ד כי אמרו רבותינו ז"ל העכו"ם דן אותם הקב״ה בלילה שהוא זמן שליטת דין ואת ישראל דן ביום שהוא זמן שליטת רחמים

Answer (score 4):

I would read as follows:

> *"Don't read it as 'in the villages' (בַּכְּפָרִים) but rather as 'heretics' (בַּכּוֹפְרִים). This is why we mention about non-Jews 'let us lodge' (נָלִינָה) and about the Jews it says 'let us get up early' (נַשְׁכִּימָה) ([Song of Songs 7:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Song_of_Songs.7.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). It appears to me with heavenly assistance, that when our Rabbis of blessed memory said that Hashem judges the non-Jews at night - this is the time when His judgement rules, and with the Jews He judges at day, as this is the time when His mercy rules."*

Comment: You wanna translate all of the Ben Yehoyadahs works lol pls do